# Entity Framework Core 7 DbContext Change Not Published

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

I'm trying to add a trigger to one of my tables and the `DbContext` change does not seem to publish with the solution.

I've added the trigger to the table in question, updated the table in question in my `DbContext` and when I run locally, it works perfectly.

```
.ToTable(tb => tb.HasTrigger("tblScene"))
```

When I publish my changes to the live server, my application throws an exception complaining that the entity isn't configured for triggers.

My local dev machine and the live server are looking at the same database and table.

It appears my old `DbContext` is "stuck" on the server...?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What do you mean? Why aren't these changes publishing correctly?